# Uses for Pizza Yeast

Tags: substitutions

I have some yeast listed as yeast for pizza. It says not recommended for bread making. Will it work for bread or angel biscuits?

Comment: Can you share a picture of the package?

Comment: This similar [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32741/what-is-pizza-crust-yeast) might be helpful.